# Calculation of applied Material area

Tags: texturing

I am an interior designer, new to blender. I would like to choose blender as my interior modelling tool but before the decision I like to know the possibility of finding applied material area in blender

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

### Geometry Nodes

[image]

[image]

You can also use a setup like this to pick the actual material rather than its index:

[image]

[image]

### Python

```py
>>> # before evaluating modifiers
>>> sum(p.area for p in C.object.data.polygons if p.material_index == 2)
8.328109342372045

>>> # after evaluating all modifiers
>>> dg = C.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
>>> ev = C.object.evaluated_get(dg)
>>> sum(p.area for p in ev.data.polygons if p.material_index == 2)
7.27077725172785
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Even though I don't understand everything it will help me in my future career.